# TinyMCE Editor Set Default Tab

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor

I removed the tabs from the WP editor using

```
wp_editor('', 'some-id', array('quicktags' => false) );
```

But sometimes when the page loads the TinyMCE field loads with the Text tab selected:

[image]

Rather than the HTML tab:

[image]

Is there a way maybe with JS / JQuery to make sure the tab is always the visual
HTML tab?

Already tried:

```
add_filter( 'wp_default_editor', create_function('', 'return "tinymce";') );
```

Comment: In my experience, WordPress remembers which view you were using when you last saved a post/page/whatever.  I have never looked into it deeper, to see if it's a cookie setting, or a user option, or what.

Comment: Yep it does, which is annoying as I didnt want to have tabs on this box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution.
I found that the problem was a JS WP setting.
A refresh of the page was required to make the editors initialise with the
new setting

```
<script>
if (getUserSetting('editor') != "tinymce") {
    setUserSetting('editor', 'tinymce');
    location.reload();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this page -- http://wp-snippets.com/set-default-editor/ * -- which looks promising, though a little out of date.  Instead of their code, I would suggest trying this:

```
add_filter( 'wp_default_editor', 'wpse101200_default_editor' );
function wpse101200_default_editor( $editor ) {
    return 'tinymce';
}
```

#### Reference

WPSeek's [`wp_default_editor()`](http://wpseek.com/wp_default_editor/) page
[`wp_default_editor()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1779) in the WordPress core source

Unfortunately, the Codex doesn't currently have a `wp_default_editor()` page.

__
* Apparently so did you.  I missed that the first time I read your question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yeah its strange that this doesnt work but I think it was being cached as a JS user setting. Ive posted my solution :)